How to view the output or logs from the Deploy phase in travis CI
I have been trying to figure out how to view the output or the logs being printed in the deploy phase in the travis CI. There are few set of changes that will be applied when the code is merged to the main branch but the changes are not being effected, hence we are forced to apply them manually. So I want to know where the it will be called and the logs so that I can creack it out. Below is how the deploy is setup
deploy:
  skip_cleanup: true
  provider: script
  on:
    branch: main
  script: .travis/deploy_to_synthetics.sh

I could not find anything relevant in the interenet for the problem I am facing. Hoping to find it here.
